# Image Center Alignment - Works but Not Perfect

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, alignment

These CSS properties center the image of any size within a container of any size:

```
display:table-cell;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
```

This is a perfect fluid image centering, however, table-cell property gives me unwanted white space on the bottom. How to avoid it? See this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8DeLQ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the container contains no text content, you could possibly add `font-size: 0;` to the container's style.  I think the unwanted whitespace is related to text content.

Comment: As @MrSlayer says add font-size: 0; and this will fix your problem;